# Go to a Type with a dynamic name (Java)

Tags: java, dynamic

I am creating a program which *should* be able to open different **perspectives**. **Perspectives**, in my program, mean different layouts of the controls. The user is able to create and pick which perspective they want to use. There is also a *Default Perspective*. The *Default Perspective* can be chosen.

Because of this I ***do not*** know how many perspectives there are, or what the *Default Perspective* is. My program uses `engine.perspective` to Read and Write to the text file (`Perspective.TXT`) in which the all the perspectives are stored. When the user creates a perspective my program automatically makes a `*.JAVA` file with all the perspective data. This is my code for reading `Perspective.TXT` and calling the correct type:

```
    ArrayList<String> ALLPRSPCTVE = Read.getAllPerspectives();
    String PRSPCTVE = Read.getDefaultPerspective();

    {
        String[] ARR = (String[]) ALLPRSPCTVE.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ALLPRSPCTVE.size(); i++) {// Set All Perspectives
            if (PRSPCTVE == ARR[i]) {

            }
        }
    }
```

How do I change the `String` returned from the method `Read.getAllPerspectives` to something JAVA will recognize as a type and go to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a software architecture problem.

But, if you want to do exactly what you say, you can still make it possible, even though it's not the right way.

- you have to call the java compiler to transform your java file into class file
- and then you can use reflection to load dynamically a class (using `Class.forName`)
- and finally instanciate this class to get a new object whose methods can be used, which would be much easier if you had a common interface for all those classes.

But, please don't do that and go on reading.

[Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing#Early_computers_and_the_Turing_test) introduced modern computer at the middle of the 20's century. One of its main features is that it dissociates data from code.

Data is the a part of memory containing variables and code is a set of instructions that manipulates those data (and other creating during programs's lifes. In java, program/code is written inside classes).

Data can then be divided into two different support : dynamic, fast and volatile memory (modern RAM) and long term storage (hard disk/database).

Note that code is data. It has to be saved on disk, loaded in memory, but it is executed. Simple data is not executed, it's mere data, read and written but not executed.

This has very practical impliactions for all applications, and you application is violating his separation of data and code has you use code (java classes) to memorize data.

Here is what you should do :

- save your data in a format that has nothing to do with java. For a simple format in which fields have values, you could use a property file ([tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)). This will be your long term storage solution.
- Then try to wrap together all functions related to reading, manipulating and writing those properties in a separate class, with public methods that your other classes will be able to call to have access to this data.

Comment: But I think in this case it is not a data <-> code problem. There are very valid cases why one would like to generate java code. CORBA, ProtoBuffers are examples of Java-source generated, there is R.* class in android - also generated and plenty of other examples where it actually makes sense, so maybe here it does make sense also?

Comment: Jarek Potiuk _does_ have a point. My program uses **super-complex** objects, and it would be a bit difficult to write it in a format other than Java! Stéphane's answer _is_ much easier, though.

Comment: I agree with Snicolas in that it would be much easier in the long run to separate your data from the code, especially later when you want to extend or modify your program. His was one of the best answers I've seen on this site all day and I'm only sorry that I can give it but one up vote.

Answer (score 1):

use Class.forName(name).newInstance()